# VSCODE No reconoce Intellisense para PHP

Tags: php, vscode

estoy aprendiendo desarrollo web y me gustaria aumentar mi velocidad de programacion, me gusta vs code por sus extensiones que facilitan mucho, sin embargo, vscode no reconoce sintaxis de php e instalado todas las extensiones para php intellisense pero ninguna me ayuda a autocompletar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: fijate abajo a la derecha si dice php en select language mode

Comment: Hola como estas, si aparece como php.

Comment: para que te reconosca el documetno deve ser .php y o el contenido del codigo debe ser <?php   pero tambien no sirve instalar todos los plugin de php pues puede provocar errores de insconsistencia. te aconsejo instalar uno he ir probando pues me ha pasado que un plugin choca con otro y se bloquea.